# Error C2661, having an issue constructing with 5 parameters, SFML 2.3

Tags: c++, constructor, sfml

I am using SFML 2.3, with visual C++.
The compiler error I am receiving is "error C2661: 'Tree::Tree' : no overloaded function takes 4 arguments".

Here is my tree class constructor.

```
 class Tree : public rectangleProperties
    {
    public:

        Tree(float x, float y, sf::Vector2f size, sf::Vector2f origin, int rotation);
        Tree() {};
        ~Tree();
```

...

```
Tree::Tree(float x, float y, sf::Vector2f size, sf::Vector2f origin, int rotation)
{
    rect.setOrigin(origin);
    rect.setSize(size);
    rect.setPosition(x, y);
    rect.setFillColor(branches);
    rect.setRotation(rotation);
}
```

Later, and the only time I call the constructor is through here:

```
squares.emplace_back(tree.initialPos_X, tree.initialPos_Y, tree.size, tree.origin, tree.rotationValue);
```

Earlier I was supplying only 4 parameters. This worked out fine, until I realized that my implementation required 5. That is when I ran the issue I am having now.

Things I have tried:

- Cleaning and rebuilding the solution
- Creating a new solution, and
  rebuilding it.

Comment: Provide a complete example, because `emplace_back` [certainly works](https://ideone.com/LSPY0E) if written correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, a mistake on my part.

I overlooked another constructor call:

```
squares.emplace_back(tree.initialPos_X, tree.initialPos_Y, tree.size, tree.rotationValue);
```